# @key-frames behave like an loading bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyway in CSS3 that i can do so the `@key-frame`-syntax behaves like an loading bar.

I want it to do when i hold on the div an green progress bar goes from 0% to 100% and redirect to another page. ?

Demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRFSpYTSZV8)!

Comment: Are you asking to recommend a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
div {
  border-left:300px solid green;
  border-right:0px solid red;
  animation:loading 10s linear; /*add vendor prefixes here*/
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  0% {border-left-width:0px;border-right-width:300px;}
  100% {border-left-width:300px;border-right-width:0px;}
}
@keyframes loading {
  0% {border-left-width:0px;border-right-width:300px;}
  100% {border-left-width:300px;border-right-width:0px;}
}
```

and then use the meta refresh tag to then reload the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://example.com/">
```

[**demo**](http://jsbin.com/OfaxEZOy/2/)

I've set the loading time to 10 seconds here. You need to change the `animation` style *and* the meta tag if you want to change the 'loading time'.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, increasing the width of a div after every interval will make it behave like a loading bar.